# How to rotate point cloud about an axis?

Tags: c++, matrix, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud of a depth image that was taken with the camera 30 degrees above the horizontal (rotated 30 degrees in z-axis). I want to translate all of the points back to their position as if the camera was at 0 degrees, which I believe I can do with the following rotation matrix:

```
|cos(30) -sin(30) 0| 
|sin(30)  cos30   0| 
|0        0       1|
```

However, when looking at the pcl method to transform a point cloud I found this:

```
pcl::transformPointCloud (const PointCloud< PointT > &cloud_in, 
PointCloud< PointT > &cloud_out, const Eigen::Matrix< Scalar, 4, 4 > &transform)
```

But why is it a 4x4 matrix as opposed to the 3x3 rotation one above?

Comment: you need a 4 x 4 matrix to perform translations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
|x||1 0 0 a| =  |x+a|
|y||0 1 0 b|    |y+b|
|z||0 0 1 c|    |z+c|
|1||0 0 0 1|    |1  |
```

In this example we moved the point (x,y,z) to the point(x+a, y+b, z+c). This can only be done with a 4 x 4 matrix.

---

```
|cos(30) -sin(30) 0 0| multiply The Matrix above. 
|sin(30)  cos30   0 0| 
|0        0       1 0|
|0        0       0 1|
```

This will give you a rotation and translation of a point.

Comment: and how would I perform a rotation about an axis?

Comment: @Aly use matrix multiplication if you want to rotate and translate a point. If you want to simply rotate just use the rotation matrix alone with the extra entries to make it a 4x4.

Answer (score 3):

The 4x4 Matrix is a Transformation matrix in the following form

```
| R    | t | 
|--------- |
|0 0 0 | 1 |
```

where `R` is your 3x3 rotation matrix and `t` is a 3x1 translation vector. In your case `t = [0,0,0]'`

For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Answer (score 0):

I like to create such affine transformation matrice like this:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
def affine_transform(translation: np.ndarray, rotation: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
      transform_matrix = np.eye(4)
      transform_matrix[:3, :3] = Rotation.from_rotvec(rotation).as_matrix()
      transform_matrix[:3, 3] = translation
      return transform_matrix
```