# Simulation of computer vision data sets

Tags: c++, matlab, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I'm studying the use of multiple cameras for computer vision applications. E.g. there is a camera in every corner of the room and the task is human tracking. I would like to simulate this kind of environment. What I need is:

- Ability to define dynamic 3D environment, e.g. room and a moving object.
- Options to place cameras at different positions and get simulated data set for each camera.

Does anyone have any experience with that? I checked out blender (http://www.blender.org), but currently I'm looking for a faster/easier to use solution.

Could you give me guidance to similar software/libraries (preferably C++ or MATLAB).

Answer (score 0):

you may find ILNumerics perfectly fits your needs:

http://ilnumerics.net

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right! you are looking to simulate camera feed from multiple camera at different positions of an environment.
I dont know of any sites or a working ready made solution, but here is how I would proceed:
Procure 3d point clouds of a dynamic environment (see  [Kinect 3d slam benchmark datasets](http://answers.ros.org/question/37052/standard-kinect-dataset)) or generate one of your own with Kinect(hoping you have Xbox kinect with you).

Once you got kinect point clouds in PCL point cloud format, you can simulate video feed from various cameras.
A pseudo code such as this will suffice:

```
#include <pcl_headers>

//this method just discards all 3d depth information and fills the pixels with rgb values
//this is like a snapshot in the pcd_viewer of pcl(point cloud library)
makeImage(cloud,image){};

pcd <- read the point clouds
camera_positions[] <- {new CameraPosition(affine transform)...}

for(camera_position in camera_positions)
    pcl::transformPointCloud(pcd,
                             cloud_out,
                             camera_position.getAffineTransform()
                            );
//Now cloud_out contains point cloud in different viewpoint
    image <- new Image();
    make_image(cloud_out,image);
    saveImage(image);
```

pcl provides a function to transform a point cloud given appropriate parameters [pcl::trasformPointCloud()](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__common.html#ga1b1184df8fe618d2014518aa262fa591)
If you wish not to use pcl then you may wish to check  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881100/how-to-rotate-point-cloud-about-an-axis)  and then followed with remaining steps.